# Biblatex uses opening parenthesis as the initial with firstinits

Tags: biblatex

Some authors use parentheses around a first name.  When using biblatex with firstinits, that opening parenthesis ends up as being the "initial" used.  Is there some way to make biblatex to use the actual initial instead (without removing the parenthesis in the bib file itself)?

Test case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[firstinits]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcite{gil}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

with test.bib:

```
@inproceedings{gil,
  author =       {Joseph (Yossi) Gil and Tali Shragai},
  title =        {Are We Ready for a Safer Construction Environment?},
  year =         {2009},
  booktitle =    {Proc. ECOOP 2009 European Conference on
                  Object-Oriented Programming},
  pages =        {495--519},
  doi =          {10.1007/978-3-642-03013-0_23},
  number =       {5653},
  series =       {Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
}
```

In the resulting bibliography, the first author's name is rendered as
`J. ( Gil`.  I would like it to be `J. Y. Gil` or perhaps even `J. Gil`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parenthesis is part of the name, so

```
author = {Joseph~(Yossi) Gil and Tali Shragai},
```

will do.

[image]

This is what I get after removing `firstinits`:

[image]